# Find a record from another table with case insensitive combined

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these two tables:

**product** has_one **address**

**address** belongs_to **product**

When I want to find a product from one city, I do:

```
Product.all.joins(:address).where(addresses: {city: @city})
```

When I want to to find all cities with case insensitive is

```
Address.all.where('lower(city) like ?', @city.downcase)
```

But now I want a record from another table **with** case insensitive **combined**. How can I do ?

I tried some ways and nothing:

```
Product.all.joins(:address).where(addresses: {"lower(city) like ?", @city.downcase})
```

gives the error:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected '}', expecting end-of-input
...ower(city) like ?", "new york"})
...
```

and the other way:

```
Product.all.joins(:address).where(addresses: {"lower(city) like ?": @city.downcase})
```

gives nothing:

```
#<Product::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3fb3fc142900>
```

Obs: I created another question because the old one was wrongly  marked as duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Product.joins(:address).where "lower(addresses.city) like ?", @city.downcase`

#### Response to comment

No idea what you're talking about "didn't track from the column city on addresses table" - what does "didn't track" mean?

Here's a console session with your models as described showing my code above working just as described:

```
[14] pry(main)> Address.create city: "New York", product: Product.first
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Address Create (43.9ms)  INSERT INTO "addresses" ("product_id", "city", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["product_id", 1], ["city", "New York"], ["created_at", "2019-02-27 18:57:37.688063"], ["updated_at", "2019-02-27 18:57:37.688063"]]
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Address:0x00007fb1e4322178 id: 1, product_id: 1, city: "New York", created_at: Wed, 27 Feb 2019 18:57:37 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Wed, 27 Feb 2019 18:57:37 UTC +00:00>
[15] pry(main)> @city = "NEW YORK"
=> "NEW YORK"
[16] pry(main)> Product.joins(:address).where "lower(addresses.city) like ?", @city.downcase
  Product Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "addresses" ON "addresses"."product_id" = "products"."id" WHERE (lower(addresses.city) like 'new york')
=> [#<Product:0x00007fb1e52f5e10 id: 1, name: "First Product", created_at: Wed, 27 Feb 2019 18:57:07 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Wed, 27 Feb 2019 18:57:07 UTC +00:00>]
```

Comment: I responded above in my answer.

Comment: Finally got there.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my mistake on testing your code.

Comment: Do you see now why I closed this as a dupe?  It really is exactly the same as the other question, except you just need to add the table name (if you want to disambiguate, although you probably don't need to), but it's the same thing.